# Formula error Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Tags: formula, url, hyperlink

I am trying to create a hyperlink formula that links the user to a google maps page displaying the address location of the lead related to the event. This is what my formula looks like right now. I have been at this for almost 2 hours and I can not get it right.

```
HYPERLINK(("https://www.google.com/maps/place/&",
"&Lead__r.Installation_Street__c&",
"&Lead__r.Installation_City__c&",
"&TEXT(Lead__r.Installation_State__c)"),
"test"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`Hyperlink` function takes following parameters

> HYPERLINK(url, friendly_name [,target]) and replace url with the Web address, replace friendly_name with the link text, and, optionally, replace target with the window or frame in which to display the content.

Following piece of code perfectly working at my DE considering Account's address information.

```
HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/maps/place/" + BillingStreet +  BillingCity +  BillingState 
, Name 
, "_Parent" 
)
```